# Why can't I see any listings when calling the ebay api's GetSellerList endpoint?

Tags: xml, rest, ebay-api

I have managed to authenticate and to call the ebay api, but when I try to get a list of my seller account's items I get an empty ItemArray object. I have called the analytics api using the same date range I use to call GetSellerList, and it returns traffic and conversion rates, so I know there were some items listed by this account for this date range.

Here is the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>access_token</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <AdminEndedItemsOnly>False</AdminEndedItemsOnly>
  <GranularityLevel>Coarse</GranularityLevel>
  <IncludeVariations>True</IncludeVariations>
  <IncludeWatchCount>True</IncludeWatchCount>
  <Pagination> PaginationType
    <EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
  <Sort>1</Sort>
  <StartTimeFrom>2022-04-15T19:09:02.768Z</StartTimeFrom>
  <StartTimeTo>2022-04-21T16:09:02.768Z</StartTimeTo>
  <!-- Standard Input Fields -->
  <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
  <!-- ... more DetailLevel values allowed here ... -->
  <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
  <MessageID> string </MessageID>
  <WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</GetSellerListRequest>
```

Here are the headers:

```
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: app_name
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetSellerList
X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING: XML
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: some_code
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: some code
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 825
Content-Type: text/xml
```

And the url : https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

method: GET.

I can't figure out why I keep getting the following response with no items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSellerListResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2022-04-21T14:44:03.680Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <CorrelationID> string </CorrelationID>
    <Version>1173</Version>
    <Build>E1173_CORE_APISELLING_19187371_R1</Build>
    <ItemArray/>
</GetSellerListResponse>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Method has to be POST.

Compat level 825 perhaps is not supported anymore: In anycase you have to use latest that should be 1247.

Try removing 'StartTimeFrom' and 'StartTimeTo'

Beside this, every month eBay decommissions some (old) Trading APIs:
I think it's not wise to start developing new apps using Trading APIs: better to use new APIs.

Comment: I tried making the changes you mentioned and I still get an empty ItemArray. Do you know which new api endpoint could provide item availability per day? I've gone through the documentation multiple times and haven't found anything.